# URL on CodeIgniter 3 ? newbie need help for tutorial

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter 3, I am trying to create a static page from this tutorial https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/static_pages.html

http://localhost/index.php/pages/view    It is work.

but my actual is like this C:\xampp\htdocs\application\views\pages
? (and not work)

why the folder is not /views/pages ?

I am getting confuse.

Also need help ! i am new to codeIgniter 3, I want to create a simple form, but they not work in the views

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

welcome.php

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
```

both added the controllers

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome');
}
}


class Form extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('form');
}
}
```

I tried these, but they not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned form action correctly. The form action should be look like this
`action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>form`" 
and in the `route.php` add route for your action.
**Example:**

```
$route['form'] = 'form/index';
```

Then you can have `$_POST` values in your Form controller.